# Splitting only long words in string

Tags: python, string, split

I have some random string, let's say :

```
s = "This string has some verylongwordsneededtosplit"
```

I'm trying to write a function trunc_string(string, len) that takes string as argument to operate on and 'len' as the number of chars after long words will be splitted.

The result should be something like that

```
str = trunc_string(s, 10)
str = "This string has some verylongwo rdsneededt osplit"
```

For now I have something like this :

```
def truncate_long_words(s, num):
"""Splits long words in string"""
words = s.split()
for word in words:
    if len(word) > num:
        split_words = list(words)
```

After this part I have this long word as a list of chars. Now I need to :

- join 'num' chars together in some word_part temporary list
- join all word_parts into one word
- join this word with the rest of words, that weren't long enough to be splitted.

Should I make it in somehow similar way ? :

```
counter = 0
for char in split_words:
    word_part.append(char)
    counter = counter+1
    if counter == num
```

And here I should somehow join all the word_part together creating word and further on

Comment: Why not use a regular expression to detect the long words. For example, this regular expression would match any words that are more that 10 consecutive non-white-space character and less than 1000 consecutive non-white-space characters:

[^\s]{10,1000}

Comment: Is this for word-wrap purposes?  If so, you could use a hyphenation library that will be much more intelligent about where it chooses to split words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not:

```
  def truncate_long_words(s, num):
     """Splits long words in string"""
     words = s.split()
     for word in words:
        if len(word) > num:
                for i in xrange(0,len(word),num):
                       yield word[i:i+num]
        else:
            yield word

 for t in truncate_long_words(s):
    print t
```

Answer (score 6):

```
def split_word(word, length=10):
    return (word[n:n+length] for n in range(0, len(word), length))

string = "This string has some verylongwordsneededtosplit"

print [item for word in string.split() for item in split_word(word)]
# ['This', 'string', 'has', 'some', 'verylongwo', 'rdsneededt', 'osplit']
```

Note: it's a bad idea to name your string `str`. It shadows the built in type.

Comment: very clean solution, i like it a lot.

Answer (score 5):

an option is the textwrap module
http://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html

example usage:

```
>>> import textwrap
>>> s = "This string has some verylongwordsneededtosplit"
>>> list = textwrap.wrap(s, width=10)
>>> for line in list: print line;
... 
This
string has
some veryl
ongwordsne
ededtospli
t
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

Abusing regex:

```
import re
def trunc_string(s, num):
   re.sub("(\\w{%d}\\B)" % num, "\\1 ", s)

assert "This string has some verylongwo rdsneededt osplit" == trunc_string("This string has some verylongwordsneededtosplit", 10)
```

(Edit: adopted simplification by Brian. Thanks. But I kept the `\B` to avoid adding a space when the word is exactly 10 characters long.)

Comment: Simpler: return re.sub('([a-zA-Z]{%d})' % num,'\\1 ',s)